# How do I find a vector when magnitude along another vector is given?

Tags: vectors

Recently during our Vector Algebra class, our professor gave us a vector A= i+2j, and asked us to find A.B and A*B if b=3 acting along C= i+j+k. He then proceeded to find B= C.b/c; I do understand that bcos theta would have been equal to B.C/c and thus B= b.c/C. Am I doing something wrong?

Note that capitals above represent the vectors while the small letters represent the magnitudes.

Comment: This question has  nothing to do with physics, you should post it on the maths site.

Comment: That site also has the awesome *[MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)*. There is also *[Short and helpful advice on using MathJax on the site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33179/short-and-helpful-advice-on-using-mathjax-on-the-site)*, including *"[Beginner's tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33179/short-and-helpful-advice-on-using-mathjax-on-the-site/33183#33183)"*.

Comment: Alright, thankyou, I will make sure to incorporate MathJax into my questions from now on :)